# show banner, native and interstitial ads on one screen

Tags: android, admob

I have setup the Native Ads in listview like setLimitOfAds(3) and setNoOfDataBetweenAds(10) using the [AdmobAdapterWrapper](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/blob/master/admobadapter/src/main/java/com/clockbyte/admobadapter/AdmobAdapterWrapper.java)

Now On Home Screen, i am showing the Banner Ads at bottom of screen and Native Ads inline in listview and when users navigates to some other activity and comes back to this home screen interstitial ad is shown.

is it ok to show the all three types of ads on one screen like this according to admob terms of use?